# Citrix XenServer, networking how

Tags: vlan, xenserver, nic

I am new to virtual servers, vlans. I am a programmer and have been assigned the task to make a stable storage server, i threw XenServer Free 5.6SP2 on an old box (HP ProLiant ML350 G5) set my raid(5), installed the footprint, all went well. very simple using the gui.
I installed my image of windows server 2003, all worked well.

Now from xencenter, i set my networks up, created a vlan. But how do i connect my VLAN to the network? Do i need a compatible switch? Do i do something with this switch? Its all new, confusing.
Do i need 1 physical NIC per VM? i was under the impression i can use my only physical NIC for as many server as i wanted (obviously with consequences)

Basically, i have a server with xenserver. windows server 2003 installed and working. just cant get it onto MY network.

I am appreciative of your time reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is have at least one Layer 3 Switch or Router which you connect at least one of the NIC's of the Xen Server too. This NIC needs to be set up as a trunk to carry all VLAN traffic. In XenCenter when you created your VLAN's you assigned them all to a specific NIC, make sure the connection between the switch and the NIC on the XenServer is set as a trunk on the switch.

On the switch, you will then need to create the same VLAN's as you have on your XenServer with the same ID's. Then, if you need to pass traffic elsewhere you can assign a port a specific VLAN ID and connect an ethernet from that port to wherever it needs to go.

Comment: Thanks, that kind of makes sense. as a solution then instead of having to buy new switches or play about. If i just put another NIC in the machine, scan it etc... can i then just give that to a VM and not have to play about? - Thanks for your answer boburob